# Criar um tipo correspondente a uma carta de baralho

Tags: c#

Preciso criar um tipo que corresponda a uma carta de baralho. Tentei assim: Criar uma classe para cada Naipe e dentro da classe criar as propriedades dessas classes que seriam as cartas em si, tipo, Ás, Valete, Rei, Dama, Dois e etc. Mas é nesse ponto que eu estou apanhando, pois precisarei usar esse baralho, como embaralhar, tirar uma carta, jogar e etc. Então vem a pergunta: Como eu crio uma carta? A pergunta não é ampla(mais de uma resposta) eu apenas tentei explicar o que deve acontecer, mas a resposta que desejo seria: Como eu crio uma carta. De preferência não coloquem código, apenas uma orientação em como fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Cara, na minha concepção o ideal seria criar uma classe `Carta`, classe `Baralho` que contenha um vetor de 52 cartas e dois `enums`, um para Naipes e um para Valor.

Dentro da classe Baralho, você teria os métodos relativos a baralho, como embaralhar, sortear uma carta, entregar uma carta do baralho e no construtor você instanciaria as 52 cartas utilizando um `for` e os enums.

Se você achar abstrato demais, eu posso fazer um edit depois, mostrando a implementação aproximada em c#...

Comment: Vou tentar fazer agora e verei se realmente entendi ou não e claro, postando tudo que fizer.

Comment: só não entendi o enum para valor.

Comment: Enum valor seria o valor da carta: A, 2, 3, ... , Q, K.

Comment: eu só não usaria um vetor com 52 posições.

Comment: @joaoeduardorf, o que eu usaria em lugar do array então? Cara, não consigo criar uma linha de raciocínio. Preciso criar um método Embaralhar, por exemplo, e claro, ele deve ser randômico e não tenho idéia de como montar meu "baralho" e embaralhar. Tá osso.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, realmente fiocou muito abstrato. Vale o que eu comentei para o joaoeduardorf.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, fiz um exemplo para ver se te ajuda e coloquei no BitBucket no seguinte endereço https://bitbucket.org/joaoeduardorf/jogo-de-cartas

Caso tenha algum problema para acessar me avisa.

[]s

Comment: boa noite. Vou dar uma olhada e pela manhã caso não tenha nenhum progresso, e se tiver posto também.

Comment: Inclui um console ontem de noite só para te mostrar as saídas.